# handling NA values in apply functions returning more than one value

Tags: r, dataframe, sapply

I have dataframe `df` with two columns `col1`, `col2`, includes `NA` values in them. I have to calculate `mean`, `sd` for them. I have calculated them separately with below code.

```
# Random generation
set.seed(12)
df <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10, replace=FALSE), 
                 col2 = sample(1:100, 10, replace=FALSE))

# Introducing null values
df$col1[c(3,5,9)] <- NA
df$col2[c(3,6)] <- NA

# sapply with return a value for a function
stat <- data.frame(Mean=numeric(length = length(df)), row.names = colnames(df))
stat[,'Mean'] <- as.data.frame(sapply(df, mean, na.rm=TRUE))
stat[,'Sd'] <- as.data.frame(sapply(df, sd, na.rm=TRUE))
```

I have tried to do both operations at a single time using the below code.

```
#sapply with return more than one value
stat[,c('Mean','Sd')] <- as.data.frame(t(sapply(c(1:length(df)),function(x)
    return(c(mean(df[,x]), sd(df[,x]))))))
```

As I failed to remove the `NA` values in the latest function, I am getting output as `NA` for both `mean`, `sd`.

Can you please give an idea on how to remove `NA` values for each function `mean`, `sd`. Also, please suggest any other possible smart ways to this.

Comment: Try: `vapply(df,function(x) c(mean(x,na.rm=TRUE),sd(x,na.rm=TRUE)),numeric(2))`

Comment: @nicola Thanks, it worked as required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an option:

```
funs <- list(sd=sd, mean=mean)
sapply(funs, function(x) sapply(df, x, na.rm=T))
```

Produces:

```
           sd       mean    
col1.value 39.34826 39.42857
col2.value 28.33946 51.625
```

If you want to get cute with the `functional` library:

```
sapply(funs, Curry(sapply, X=df), na.rm=T)
```

Does the same thing.

Comment: `funs <- data.frame(sd, mean)` gives me an error `cannot coerce class ""function"" to a data.frame`. Do I need to load any package for overcoming this error ?

Comment: @Prradep Just use `list(sd=sd, mean=mean)`.  Not sure why you get that error and not I, perhaps and R version difference.

Comment: Yes, No error with the list function. I'm using R version 3.1.2. Does this problem has been fixed in New version ??

Comment: @Prradep somehow loading `data.table` allows the data.frame trick to work, not sure why.  I can replicate your failure if I don't load `data.table`.