# Apply list of functions to list of values

Tags: r, apply

In reference to **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758043/handling-na-values-in-apply-functions-returning-more-than-one-value)**, I was trying to figure out the simplest way to apply a list of functions to a list of values.  Basically, a nested `lapply`.  For example, here we apply `sd` and `mean` to built in data set `trees`:

```
funs <- list(sd=sd, mean=mean)
sapply(funs, function(x) sapply(trees, x))
```

to get:

```
              sd     mean
Girth   3.138139 13.24839
Height  6.371813 76.00000
Volume 16.437846 30.17097
```

But I was hoping to avoid the inner `function` and have something like:

```
sapply(funs, sapply, X=trees)
```

which doesn't work because `X` matches the first `sapply` instead of the second.  We can do it with `functional::Curry`:

```
sapply(funs, Curry(sapply, X=trees))
```

but I was hoping maybe there was a clever way to do this with positional and name matching that I'm missing.

Comment: hadley wrote an entire chapter on this topic: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#lists-of-functions , since I am not any more clever than he is I know of no better way of doing this

Comment: Not simpler, but nice if you want a tidy data.frame at the end: `library(purrr) ; map_df(funs, ~map_df(trees, .x), .id = 'statistic')`

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Since `mapply` use ellipsis `...` to pass vectors (atomics or lists) and not a named argument (X) as in `sapply, lapply, etc ...` you don't need to name the parameter `X = trees` if you use mapply instead of sapply :

```
funs <- list(sd = sd, mean = mean)

x <- sapply(funs, function(x) sapply(trees, x))

y <- sapply(funs, mapply, trees)

> y
              sd     mean
Girth   3.138139 13.24839
Height  6.371813 76.00000
Volume 16.437846 30.17097
> identical(x, y)
[1] TRUE
```

You were one letter close to get what you were looking for ! :)

Note that I used a list for `funs`because I can't create a dataframe of functions, I got an error.

```
> R.version.string
[1] "R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)"
```

Comment: Very clever, will definitely use this in the future; I think the key feature is that `mapply` happens to accept the function argument as the first argument, so this all works.

Answer (score 15):

You're basically going to need an anonymous function of some sort because there would be no other way to distinguish named parameters to the two different `sapply` calls. You've already shown an explicit anonymous function and the `Curry` method. You could also use `magrittr`

```
 library(magrittr)
 sapply(funs, . %>%  sapply(trees, .))
 # or .. funs %>% sapply(. %>%  sapply(trees, .))
```

but the point is you need *something* there to do the splitting. The "problem" is that `sapply` dispatches to `lapply` which is an [internal function](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/baeb831c9dc6af2e23d924b31002431343b4d596/src/main/apply.c#L34) that seems determined to place the changing values as the beginning of the function call. You need something to reorder parameters and due to to the identical sets of parameter names it's not possible to tease that apart without a helper function to take care of the disambiguation.

The `mapply` function does allow you to pass a list to "MoreArgs" which allows a way to get around the named parameter conflict. This is intended to split between the items you should vectorize over and those that are fixed. Thus you can do

```
mapply(sapply, funs, MoreArgs=list(X=trees))
#               sd     mean
# Girth   3.138139 13.24839
# Height  6.371813 76.00000
# Volume 16.437846 30.17097
```

Comment: Nice one with `MoreArgs`.  I guess `magrittr` could be `funs %>% sapply(. %>%  sapply(X=trees))`?  Definitely had a bit of a double take seeing the `.` as the first element in the pipe.

Comment: Yeah, i added that as well although I think the first version is more clear. To he honest though, I think the best way is just to use the explicit anonymous function as you did the first time: `sapply(funs, function(x) sapply(trees, x))`

Comment: agreed; I edited again to remove an extra `.`, but not 100% sure I follow my own logic...

Comment: @BrodieG Nice work getting rid of the extra `.`. It works and looks "simple", but I would personally say it's probably too difficult for a programmer to quickly read and understand what it's doing. `sapply` calls just naturally have a certain rhythm that this breaks. But to each his own.

Answer (score 6):

Another approach using `purrr` would be:

```
require(purrr)

funs <- list(sd=sd, mean=mean)
trees %>% map_df(~invoke_map(funs, ,.), .id="id")
```

**Important**: Note the empty second argument of `invoke_map` to match by position. See `?purrr::invoke_map` examples.

which gives you:

```
Source: local data frame [3 x 3]

      id        sd     mean
   <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
1  Girth  3.138139 13.24839
2 Height  6.371813 76.00000
3 Volume 16.437846 30.17097
```

Instead of rownames this approach gives you a column `id` containing the original columns.

Comment: When using purrr 0.2.2 (and possibly earlier versions, as well—I haven't checked), it is required to use `invoke_map_df()`, rather than `invoke_map()`, to get the result shown.

Comment: @egnha, thats strange. For me it works just fine with `purrr_0.2.2`. Using `invoke_map_df` leads to `Error: cannot convert object to a data frame`... What version of R are you using?

Comment: That's puzzling. I'm using R 3.3.0; ran code in a fresh session with just purrr (and no init files loaded by R). Morally, `invoke_map_df` is the correct `invoke_map*` to apply (and works correctly on my machine), since `map_df` makes a data frame by binding rows (unless I've misunderstood something).

Comment: What version of dplyr are you using? (`map_df` uses `dplyr::bind_rows`)

Answer (score 1):

Though not as edifying nor as elegant as the solution presented by @Floo0, here is yet another take using [tidyr](https://github.com/hadley/tidyr) and [dplyr](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr):

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

fns <- funs(sd = sd, mean = mean)
trees %>% 
    gather(property, value, everything()) %>% 
    group_by(property) %>% 
    summarise_all(fns)

#   A tibble: 3 x 3
#   property        sd     mean
#      <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>
# 1    Girth  3.138139 13.24839
# 2   Height  6.371813 76.00000
# 3   Volume 16.437846 30.17097
```

This sequence of operations does a decent job of signaling intent, at the cost of extra verbosity.