# apply list of functions on multiple dataframes with different number of inputs

Tags: r, dataframe, apply, sapply, mapply

In reference to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30758043/handling-na-values-in-apply-functions-returning-more-than-one-value), I was wondering if multiple dataframes can be used based on the function. I mean, in the example in the linked question, we have discussed only about `mean`,`sd`. If there is a requirement to add two sample `t-test` to the other two functions, we need to use another `data.frame` besides the one used for `mean` and `sd`.

Do you have any suggestions in this scenario ?

Copying the example from the linked thread:

```
# Random generation
set.seed(12)
df1 <- data.frame(col1 = sample(1:100, 10, replace=FALSE), 
                 col2 = sample(1:100, 10, replace=FALSE))
set.seed(16)
    df2 <- data.frame(col3 = sample(10:90, 10, replace=FALSE), 
                     col4 = sample(10:90, 10, replace=FALSE))

# Introducing null values
df1$col1[c(3,5,9)] <- NA
df1$col2[c(3,6)] <- NA
df2$col3[c(5,8)] <- NA
df2$col4[c(4,5,9)] <- NA

# sapply with return a value for a function
stat <- data.frame(Mean=numeric(length = length(df1)), row.names = colnames(df1))
stat[,c('Mean','Sd')] <- vapply(df1,function(x) c(mean(x,na.rm=TRUE),sd(x,na.rm=TRUE)),numeric(2))
```

How to inlude the function `t.test(df1$col1,df2$col3)` in this ?

```
funs <- list(sd=sd, mean=mean)
sapply(funs, function(x) sapply(df1, x, na.rm=T))
```

Expected output: (something like the below in a dataframe 2x5)

```
mean(col1) sd(col1) mean(col3) sd(col3) t.test(col1,col3)$p.value
mean(col2) sd(col2) mean(col4) sd(col4) t.test(col2,col4)$p.value
```

Comment: The `t.test` output is a `list`.  If you need to extract the p.value.  `stat['p.value'] <- mapply(function(x,y) t.test(x,y)$p.value, df1, df2)`, but again it is not clear what the expected output is

Comment: @akrun I have included expected output, check if that makes sense ?

Comment: Try `lst <- list(df1, df2);
cbind(do.call(cbind,lapply(lst, function(.df) vapply(.df, function(x) c(mean(x, na.rm=TRUE), sd(x, na.rm=TRUE)), numeric(2)))), p.val=mapply(function(x,y) t.test(x,y)$p.value, df1, df2) )`

Comment: Maybe I'm just out of it cause it's almost 5am here, but isn't the `vapply()` and assignment in your initial block of code incorrect? The mean and sd of col1 will be assigned to the col1 and col2 Means, and the mean and sd of col2 will be assigned to the col1 and col2 Sds. I think you need a `t()` call to make it correct. Or maybe I just need some sleep...

Comment: @bgoldst yes, you are right. I have included it as an example list functions over a single dataframe. I would like to have one like that for scenario like this ?

Comment: @akrun sorry for coming late, the code will serve the purpose, but is there any way to list all the functions as well ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get your comment.

Comment: To include the functions in a list `list(mean, sd, t.test)` something like this.